# MVC Required Too many arguments to public sub new()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, data-annotations

I have created new MVC project with internet template.
Now I would like to change default required message from "Username is to required" to some text in my language.
But when I try to enter string in required attribute compiler complains with message in title.
Example:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class LogOnModel
Private userNameValue As String

<DisplayName("Banana split")> _
<Required("Text in my language")> _
Public Property UserName() As String
    Get
        Return userNameValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        userNameValue = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

I have also tried to put something like:

```
<Required(ErrorMessage="Text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax, notice the `:` before `=`

```
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Text in my language")>
```